# Validate text column against [Me]'s Display Name

Tags: lookup-column, display-name

I have two lists in SharePoint 2013

1. Trips
2. Drivers

Drivers has a column called **Active Driver** that is a single line of text formatted "Lastname, Firstname". Drivers also has a separate column that is a Person column which I am not using for the lookup (since I only want to show active drivers based on other logic - irrelevant here).

Trips has a lookup column that looks up the "Active Driver" column.

Trips has a View which I want to filter by Active Driver is equal to `[Me]`. But it's not working. It's as though I need something like `Text([Me])` but that is not working either.

Comment: `[Me]` will only work for a Person column.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because the Lookup in your Trips List to the Person value in the Drivers list is a **reference** and not the actual value.
And [Me] is old (pre SharePoint 2007) legacy code that (when the View is compiled for the current user) does a a server-side comparison on current user Name and the **value** in the field you compare with.
It does not perform the Lookup like the rest of the SharePoint View display code does.
(*I think* it is the same reason why you can not use Lookup Columns or other non Text/Number columns in Calculated Column Formulas)

Ways around it

- Copy the actual **value** to (an extra) column in your Trips list with a workflow
- If you only need it for View Display purposes:

  - use CSR (Client Side Rendering) *SP2013/Online only* to filter on Current User
  - add JavaScript code to every ListItem which hides the item if it doesn't match with the current user

Comment: Thanks Danny, 
Based on your comment that "[Me]... does a server-side comparison on current user Name and the value in the field you compare with" does that mean if instead I used a single-line-of-text field that included the username, that then I could compare [Me]? I've tried that, using the login name formatted i:0#.w|domain\username but that's not working either. Is there a specific format that [Me] checks against?

Comment: *AFAIK* [Me] can only be compared with a Person column.. in the same list.